# skip some bytes of file in Multipart form-data

Tags: react-native, multipartform-data

is this possible to skip some bytes of file in `Multipart` form-data?

for example:

> I want to upload 1Gb file to server. The server receives 700Mb of file and
>   store it. 
>   Next time server tell me ok! send me next 300Mb. and i want
>   to skip the first 700Mb of the file and send next 300Mb of the file to a server.